# jQuery Problem: Can't read href attr for some reason

Tags: jquery, href

not sure why this is returning undefined.  The element exists and I even tried to change the ID property to make sure it wasn't conflicting with anything in the namespace.

I also am importing jquery, so that's not the issue.  The double brackets are for Django context variables

Any thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//return to search page with appropriate GET parameters
var parameters=window.location.search +'';

$('#back').attr('href',$('#back').attr('href')+parameters);



</script>   

<div id="content"> 
<a id="back" href="{{site}}search/"><< Return to Search Results </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're modifying the attribute after the DOM is fully loaded by putting your code inside a call to [$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var parameters=window.location.search +'';
        $('#back').attr('href',$('#back').attr('href')+parameters);
    });
</script>
```

The code as it appears in your question will fail if the `script` tag is inside the `body`, because the Javascript will be invoked as it's parsed, and at that point in time, your anchor tag has yet to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.. maybe you're breaking it by using < instead of &lt;

```
  <div id="content"> 
    <a id="back" href="{{site}}search/">&lt;&lt;Return to Search Results </a>
    </div>
        <div id='result'>result</div>

$(document).ready(function(){


    var parameters=window.location.search +'/';

$('#back').attr('href',$('#back').attr('href')+parameters);
   $('#result').html($('#back').attr('href'));


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector, $("#back") selects an *ARRAY* of controls. You want to address the [0] element of the array, like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function hrefOnClick() {
            var myA = $("#testHref");
            alert(myA[0].href);

        }

    </script>
```

for an anchor tag that looks like this:

```
<a id="testHref" href="http:\\www.stackoverflow.com" onclick="hrefOnClick();">click me</a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you read the question, but this is totally irrelevant and unrelated. The jQuery methods, such as `attr()` are written to operate on arrays, so indexing the first element won't change anything. That, and his selector should be returning 1 element anyways because IDs should be unique.

Comment: Yes, IDs should be unique, the jquery selector always returns an array. Depending on when OP wants the code to run, putting it inside the <script> tags without a ready handler will run the script on page load, but as the OP pointed out attr() call returned undefined. When addressing the [0] element produced the result that I believed OP to want.